# access speed, perl binary hash file vs mySQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I currently use a lot of perl binary hash files stored in multiple file locations for loading data into this cgi website. I am debating whether mySQL would be faster or slower if I decide to store my data there.

Any insights? I understand that perl hashes are completely loaded into memory.

Gordon

Comment: What do you mean by a "binary hash file"?  Are you using a tied hash with something like [DB_File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DB_File)?

Comment: Note 'out of the box' MySQL usually has default confuguration settings for very old hardware and can be drastically tuned up to the point where most data sites in cache. I'm looking at my recently installed mysql 5.1 on deb6. opening comment "The following values assume you have at least 32M ram"! The online documentation is a bit better, but still serveral years out of date: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html

Comment: @snoopy: Perhaps the reason it's "several years out of date" is because you're looking at the MySQL 5.0 docs. Try switching the 5.0 to 5.5 in the URL for something a bit more current: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-parameters.html

Comment: The binary hash file is done using the http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.25/Storable.pm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a database means your lookups will be slower but your script will use less memory.

Using in-memory hashes means your lookups will be faster but your script will use more memory.

If you're not having memory troubles and your hashes will never get larger, then continue to use them.

If you're not having memory troubles and your hashes will get larger, then look into using a database.

If you're having memory troubles, use a database.

If you want to use a database for the sake of using a database (i.e. to learn new skills) then use a database.

Comment: Another point to mention about a database is that if you ever expand beyond a single machine, then a database is easier then trying to keep multiple db files in sync across multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

If a Perl hash handles your data needs, you probably don't need the overhead of a full blown SQL database.  There are a lot of storage alternatives for key->value storage such as the Berkley DB and the entire "NOSQL" movement.  Google those and you'll find lots of info.  Perl interfaces exist in CPAN for many of these.

Comment: MySQL (using MyISAM) is a really fast key-value store. And you also get the benefit of being able to use SQL to let normal people query it without having to write code.

Comment: @mpeters: Of course, you need to implement solid user authentication and (probably) some serious input sanitization if you're going to execute arbitrary user-provided SQL. And your definition of "normal people" is somewhat different than mine...

Answer (score 1):

Speaking strictly in terms of speed, finding single, exactly-matching keys in a straight in-memory hash is about as good as you can get unless your data is amenable to being put into an array.  (i.e., It will be accessed solely by a series of numeric keys which form a mostly-contiguous range starting at 0.)

If you have multiple possible keys that you might need to search on (e.g., both Name and Employee ID) or if you need to do searches which aren't strictly equality-based (e.g., "Find all employees with the last name 'Smith'"), then you're going to be slowed down significantly by the need to search through hash keys and a database starts looking a lot better.

Another factor in overall performance is that you mentioned that your hashes are "stored in multiple file locations".  If you're only doing one or a few lookups, reading the hashes into memory from those files takes time also, which again tilts things in favor of using a database, which will minimize the amount of unneeded data that gets read from disk.

So it depends a lot on how you need to access your data and your access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what has already been mentioned, you will get more scalability with a database, since it can be off-loaded to another server. MySQL has been working for years at making complex lookups faster, which is code you don't have to write. With a binary hash, it is up to you to worry about syncing to disk without slowing down your application, ensuring atomicity of disk writes, maintenance and optimization, and handling synchronization when several processes to access the data at once. Using a database deals with all of that for you.

On the other side of the equation, databases mean an extra delay for I/O as queries are sent and results received over the network or local socket. Don't underestimate the time you can spend here, especially as your data set grows.

It is often a good idea to write a generic API over the hash driver. Then, when scalability or concurrency becomes an issue, you can just add a MySQL driver and migrate your data over. Granted, that's a big "just", but it's a fast and simple way forward that limits the impact on the rest of your software if a change becomes necessary